# Go from file to file tree in neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

I am a newbie at neovim. I basically entered a file and can't go back to file tree in a vanilla NeoVim configuration.

Funny enough I couldn't find a way to do this. Even in the nvim tutor.

I don't want to exit the editor so:

```
:q
:wq
:qa
```

Won't work

How do I go back to the file tree after I enter a file?

Comment: Did you try `:bp`? In nvim it should bring you back to the previous buffer even when it was a directory listing

Comment: @etuardu That worked perfectly. Make an answer please. So I can give you some points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:bp` (short form of `:bprevious`) to move to the previous buffer, in nvim it will work even in case it was a directory listing.

Comment: You can also Ctrl-O / Ctrl-I for switching back and forth between your file history

Answer (score 0):

Another way of always returning to the files tree is by typing:

```
:Explore
```

This works better than writing `:bp` as it isn't actually intended to return to the files tree but to the previous buffer(whatever that is).

The only purpose of running `:Ntree` is to actually go to the files tree.